# How to cache HTMLResponse with fastapi-cache

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, starlette

Using the example and a simple HTML coder (value.encode() and value.decode()) I was not able to cache html responses in fastapi.,

```
@app.get("/", response_class=HTMLResponse)
@cache(expire=60)
async def read_items(request: Request, col=None, name: str = None):
```

throws exception

tried custom encoder as per https://pypi.org/project/fastapi-cache2/ fastapi-cache2 documentation

```
class ORHTMLCoder(Coder):
    @classmethod
    def encode(cls, value: Any) -> bytes:
        return value.body

    @classmethod
    def decode(cls, value: bytes) -> Any:
        return HTMLResponse(value.decode().replace(r'\n','\n' ))
```

Answer (score 0):

outside the HTML Coder I had to add this to the templateResponse for it to work.

```
        template_str = templates.get_template("./cdr/index.html").render({"request": request, 'array': COL_NAMES_ONE,"df": df_filtered.to_html(classes='table table-striped table-hover')})
        return HTMLResponse(template_str)
```

not sure why but  templates.TemplateResponse() doesnt work as expected with the encoding.